# Product Master in openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

'Warranty' float field is available in product.template in base code, I inherit it and override into integer field in my custom module and work fine but the problem arise when I update all the module and upgrade the DB the warranty field set to 0. And in DB the warranty field is replicated whenever I update the DB like 'warranty1', 'warranty2'.......

So how to inherit the base float field and override it as integer.

What I have done is:

```
'warranty': fields.float('Warranty'), # in product_template (base code) 

'warranty': fields.integer('Warranty'), # (customize module)
 _defaults= {

            'warranty': 12,
           }
```

What is the reason for replication of warranty field in db and field created under double precision.

Comment: Have you check the same things for the new database ..??

Comment: yes, In new DB also it reflect the same

Comment: Its mean that you are going to wrongly customize that field